# get all registered route in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to return all registered route in my project.

i use this code for retur nall routes :

```
const app = require("express");
let routers = app._router.stack
  .filter((r) => r.route)
  .map((r) => {
    return {
      method: Object.keys(r.route.methods)[0].toUpperCase(),
      path: r.route.path,
    };
  });
```

but it not worked and show me this error :

> (node:13092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

**Edit :**

my routes :

```
    const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const roleRouter=require('./role');
const userRouter=require('./user');
const managerRouter=require('./manager');
const accessRouter=require('./access');
const settingRouter=require('./setting');


router.use('/role',roleRouter);

router.use('/user',userRouter);

router.use('/manager',managerRouter);

router.use('/access',accessRouter);

router.use('/setting',settingRouter);

module.exports=router;
```

and use that in the main js file :

```
   app.use(require("./routes/index"));
```

**how can i return all routes in my projects ???**

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek    "express": "^4.17.1",

Answer (score 4):

the `app` supposed to be created with express function

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

then you can get all of the registered routes, make sure to put this line after you register your app routes

```
console.log(app._router);
```

So the full code will look like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

console.log(app._router); // undefined

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

console.log(app._router.stack); // showing routes

app.listen(port)
```

EDIT:

To return all of your routes from your API endpoint, you can do this (not sure why you want to do this though)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(app._router.stack);
})

app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    // This route will also be listed when you call "/" 
    res.send();
})

app.listen(port)
```

Comment: it not worked . it show me this `undefined`

Comment: Where did you put the `console.log(app._router);`? it's supposed to be after you register all of your app routes. Check my full code edit

Comment: i'm not need to use this code in the startup file .  i want useing this code in the controller .for exmaple send request to the from api and then return list of routes

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, are you saying that you want an api endpoint that returns list of the express app routes?

Comment: yes  . . . . . .

Comment: Check my last edit, does it answer your question?

Comment: not man . it show me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined`

Comment: Need more information from your code, please put your routes code on your post.

Comment: i update the question